# How can I use a GMP library I just built from source?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, shared-libraries, gmp

I've got a tiny C program with the following header:

```
#include <gmp.h>
```

I compile it doing:

```
gcc test.c -o test.o -L/gmp_install/lib -lgmp
```

And then I can run it fine. But it is using the "stock" GMP library on my system.

Now I'd like to compile it using another version of the GMP lib, which I installed locally and I can't make it work.

The new library is apparently installed in `/usr/local/lib`:

```
... $  ls -l /usr/local/lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 1276320 Jun 15 02:22 libgmp.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff     914 Jun 15 02:22 libgmp.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff      16 Jun 15 02:22 libgmp.so -> libgmp.so.10.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff      16 Jun 15 02:22 libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff  528715 Jun 15 02:22 libgmp.so.10.2.0
```

But no matter what I try, it's apparently the old library that is used.

Even using:

```
gcc perf.c -o perf.o -O3 -L/ -lgmp
```

But it's using the GMP version in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

What is the correct way to use the GMP version in /usr/local/bin, knowing I'd like to keep the old version too?

Also, once the executable is created, is there an easy way to see which library it shall use at runtime? (can I create the executable with one version of GMP and then execute it with another version of GMP, knowing the lib is dynamically linked?)

Comment: Don't forget to say which system you are running on. You need -I/path/include so the compiler can find gmp.h, -L/path/lib so it can find libgmp.{so,a} at compile time, and depending on the system -Wl,-R/path/lib so it can find libgmp.so.42 at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Do two things:

1. Use `-L/usr/local/lib` flag while compiling
2. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable while running your program to have `/usr/local/lib`. Thus, if you are using a bash shell, you will have to do something like

   `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

   `$ ./your_program`

to use the `/usr/local/lib` version at runtime. Also, in order to see which one it will use at runtime, you can always do `ldd <your binary name>` which will print out all the dynamic dependencies.